# zathura - The not-so-lightweight pdf reader

Tags: memory, pdf, zathura

Long time user of `zathura` since it really is 'lightweight' in that there are no extraneous features. However, I often find myself running out of memory due to having several pdf's open at once. From `htop`:

```
VIRT   RES   SHR  S  Command
1171M  266M 41116 S  zathura --config-dir=/tmp/tmp.asdfj a-pdf.pdf
1171M  266M 41116 S  zathura --config-dir=/tmp/tmp.asdfj a-pdf.pdf  
1171M  266M 41116 S  zathura --config-dir=/tmp/tmp.asdfj a-pdf.pdf  
1171M  266M 41116 S  zathura --config-dir=/tmp/tmp.asdfj a-pdf.pdf
```

For some reason opening a single pdf (`a-pdf` in this case) results in four instances of zathura running, and they all use around 250M, which does not seem right at all. Why are there four instances for one pdf? Killing the instance will recover around 1G of memory.

Comment: https://git.pwmt.org/pwmt/zathura/-/issues

Comment: https://git.pwmt.org/pwmt/zathura/-/issues/88 https://git.pwmt.org/pwmt/zathura/-/issues/153

It looks like the project is essentially dead. Lots of reproducible bugs in their tracker with zero comments.

Comment: That's disappointing. Have tried to find similar readers in the past without much luck.

Comment: Firefox and Chromium based web browsers have been able to read PDFs for years now. I'm not sure why people insist on dedicated *readers*.

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov More to the point I guess.. If it so easy to adopt in a browser, why can't we have a minimalist program to display, navigate and search a pdf document.

Comment: Also, the ability to navigate with vim commands with zathura is really nice.

Comment: https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/addon/vimium-ff/

Comment: Since switched to `mupdf` which is nice, lightweight alternative. The idea of using a web browser alongside applications like `vimlatex` or `ranger` is silly.